# How to identify iOS Universal apps from apple RSS feed

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, rss, app-store

I'm working on an iOS app review website and have taken a look at the tools Apple provides, such as iTunes RSS feeds and API.

However, I do not know how to distinguish an iOS Universal app from the other iOS app types (iPhone and iPad only).

Any idea how to make this distinction so I can segregate iOS Universal apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I checked out the xml and there doesn't appear to be an element that specifies it's universality.  But the link contained in the feed that points to the app's page on itunes.apple.com contains this bit of code:

```
<p><span class="app-requirements">Requirements: </span>
Compatible with iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad. Requires iOS 3.1 or later
</p>
```

and if I'm correct you can probably get at that bit of html by targeting the class ("app-requirements" in this case) and maybe do a bit of Regex magic to check if ipad and/or iphone is contained therein.

Hope this help...not clued up enough to go into exact details.

Comment: I agree, a secondary scrape is probably needed, but I think Luis is looking for apps that'll work native on iPad, not in iPhone emulation mode (compatible with iPad just means it'll run, but not necessarily full screen.)  Instead, try searching for this snippet: <div class="fat-binary-blurb"><span class="fat-binary-badge"></span><span>This app is designed for both iPhone and iPad</span></div>

Comment: @jason I'm new to iOS dev so could you explain what you meant by "runing native on iPad, not iPhone Emulatiom..." Perhaps have a small script to handle the RSS from Apple and just cut out the one not containing the above search (ipad) and create?a new RSS feed just for your app.

Comment: most iPod apps will run on the iPad, but not in native 1024x768 resolution - it's either a 320x480 window centred on the screen or you can do s 2x magnification to 640x960. The fat binary tag indicates that the app has layouts for the bigger screen.

Comment: Thanks so much for the fat binary tag suggestion.  That may just do the trick.  I'm going to check it out and see if this provides the solution.  I never thought about bifurcating according to screen layout size.  Thanks again.

Comment: @jason ah! got it! Understood thanks. @Luis Jason gets the credit for this one I think, providing a more exact technical answer!

Answer (score 0):

check if this kind of feeds work for you..

http://appstorefeeds.com/

this has classification for iphone, ipad paid/free. check this out once

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately this is the same information provided by Apple's iTunes RSS feeds and comes without Universal app classification.